# Is there a way to have IDE PHP code autocompletion when passing string argument?

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I would like to write something like

```
/**
 * @param 'apple'|'banana'|'pear' $fruit
 */
function getFruit(string $fruit)
{ ... }
```

so that my IDE (PhpStorm) shows possible options when I type

```
getFruit('<caret>')
```

What are possible workarounds if there is no such feature (which would be a BIG shame)?

Comment: This issue is currently under discussion [here](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/557)

Comment: @DanielO This is sad

Comment: It's not allowed by phpdoc now. So far it will be useful to view phpdoc information in PhpStorm in the quick documentation popup window by pressing Ctrl+Q on the method name.

Comment: You can use word completion: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/auto-completing-code.html#hippie_completion

Comment: @VladLuchansky thanks, your solution may help, but is far from desired, because it does not give developer confidence that suggested word belongs to the list of valid arguments.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Yes, we need to wait for the solution on the PHPDoc issue linked above. So far that's the best PhpStorm can suggest.

Comment: @VladLuchansky I don't sure why wait for PHPDoc (whose team has abandoned psr-5), but anyway, thanks for feedback and clarifying. BTW if anyone is interested please vote for issue, i've created: https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-42220